# what if there is no welcome file list in web.xml in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

Generally, welcome file lists are used to show first page of application. What if, in my web.xml i don't have welcome file lists. In this case, which file will be shown as home page of my application? I just have few filters in web.xml?

Comment: why not try it before asking this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a HTTP 404 error page will be shown, which can be either the servletcontainer's default one or the one which you definied as `<error-page>` for `<error-code>404</error-code>` in `web.xml`.

Or, if the servletcontainer is configured to show directory listings by default, then it will be shown instead. In Tomcat, it's configureable as `listings` init param of the default servlet in `/conf/web.xml`.

Or, if you have a (poorly designed?) servlet or filter which is been mapped on `/*` or `/` and does not do its job properly, then you will see its response body instead.

If you experiment a bit and try it yourself, then you'll see it yourself as well. Here's a screen of Tomcat's default HTTP 404 error page:

[image]

And here's a screen of Tomcat's default directory listing:

[image]

Comment: No, it is not showing HTTP 404 error page. Does it execute all filters one by one and stops when it finds atleast one of them with doFilter method?

Comment: Yes, that's also a possible cause. Check all servlets and filters which is been mapped on `/*` or `/` if they do their job as intended, particularly the servlets as it's considered a poor practice to map them on a global URL pattern.

Comment: @BalusC If you do not define Welcome Pages, WebLogic Server looks for the following files in the following order and serves the first one it finds:

    index.html
    index.htm
    index.jsp
This is what I found here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1026980

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be specific to Tomcat 7 Server.

If you do not define Welcome Pages, Tomcat 7 looks for the following files in the following order and serves the first one it finds:

index.html, index.htm, index.jsp

So if none of the above files are present, a HTTP Status 404 error is thrown.

Comment: Nirmal, This is not an answer. It's a question in itself and should be posted as such for others to provide you an answer. In your question, you can point to this question for reference.

Comment: @zEro, Sorry for the previous entry. modified it now.